# Is there a way how to fix the delay that happens when the user checks the box?

Tags: react-native

What I'm trying to do is the user to have the possibility to choose his contact(his contact list) and to save them.
The problem is when the user clicks the checkbox to chose the phone number, it delays 2-3 seconds.
After 2-3 seconds the checkbox is completed.

```
  const onChangeValue = (item) => {
    if (itemChecked.includes(item.phoneNumbers[0].digits)) {
      itemChecked.splice(itemChecked.indexOf(item.phoneNumbers[0].digits), 1);
    } else {
      itemChecked.push(item.phoneNumbers[0].digits);
      setCheckedBox(true);
    }

    setItemChecked(itemChecked);
    console.log(itemChecked);
    // console.log(item);
  };

return(
   <View>
       {itemChecked.includes(item.phoneNumbers[0].digits) === false ? (
                <CheckBox
                  style={{ width: 15, height: 15 }}
                  right={true}
                  checked={false}
                  onPress={() => {
                    onChangeValue(item, index);
                  }}
                />
              ) : (
                <CheckBox
                  style={{ width: 15, height: 15, paddingTop: 8 }}
                  right={true}
                  checked={true}
                  onPress={() => {
                    onChangeValue(item, index);
                  }}
                />
           )}
   </View>
);

How can I solve the delay?
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try another ui library for checkbox?
If not, u can check React-Native-Elements and Native-Base

Comment: I have already used React-Native-Elements